# Using a method to create a string literal (str)

Tags: rust

I have hit the famous Rust learning curve trying to write my first nontrivial method. This method takes a value and an `App` struct and based on if a `player` struct held within the `App` struct has a value equal to the index passed to the method, it pushes a `piece` char held within `player` on a string and returns it. Here is the code:

```
fn player_char<'a>(app: &'a App, index: u16) -> String {
    let mut player_char = String::from("|");
    for p in app.players.iter() {
        if u16::from(p.index) == index {
            player_char.push(p.piece);
        }
    }
    for i in 0..(7 - player_char.len()) {
        player_char.push_str(" ");
    }
    player_char.push_str("|");
    player_char
}
```

I created this code so that I could automatically generate string literals to pass to a method that formats and displays text to the terminal. When I use the method like this:

```
       Span::styled(str::from(player_char(app, 0)), Style::default().bg(Color::White).fg(Color::Black))
```

It creates a temporary that is freed before use, since `as_str()` creates a &str. The method `Span` has this implementation:

```
pub struct Span<'a> {
    pub content: Cow<'a, str>,
    pub style: Style,
}
```

How could I use my method, `player_char`, to produce an argument that satisfies the parameters of `Span`?

*constructive criticism of my code and question would also be greatly appreciated*

Comment: If this is `Cow`, what's the problem? Just use `Cow::Owned`.

Comment: _"I created this code so that I could automatically generate string literals"_ → you can't "generate" string literals, since if you generate them then they're no longer literals.

Comment: How is the `Span::styled` method defined? And more generally where does this `Span` come from? Is it something you wrote or does it come from a public crate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implementation [`impl<'a> From<String> for Cow<'a, str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#impl-From%3CString%3E) which allows conversion of an owned `String` into a `Cow<'a, str>`.  Just invoke `.into()` on the owned `String` to consume it and produce the `Cow` value:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

struct Span<'a> {
    pub content: Cow<'a, str>,
}

fn make_string() -> String {
    String::new()
}

fn main() {
    let span = Span { content: make_string().into() };
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=69715e6a4e24eb87901acaaeeae3ade0))